Where and How to Define Custom Android Sound with Firebase Cloud Messaging
When using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications to an Android device, with a custom sound, I was under the impression that this is defined in the android/notification/sound section of the JSON in the message definition in your cloud function.
This would mean that we can change the custom sound on a per message basis... provided all the custom sounds are included properly in our app bundle.
However, when I research/troubleshoot why my sounds are not working (it just plays the default sound on the client device), I have run into advice both here on stackoverflow and via chat-GPT that suggests the solution is to attribute a custom sound to the custom notification channel using channel.setSound(...).
But this would mean that any given channel can only have one sound... and will always have that sound.
It also begs the question why there is any sound parameter in the JSON definition of the message at all if it is already defined and overridden by the channel itself.
So... which is it?

Based on: Custom Android notification sound and No notification sound when sending notification from firebase in android sort by new to old, the 'sound parameter' was for pre Oreo now superseded by notification channels.
